# проблема с google-services.json

Tags: android, json, google-maps, firebase, google-services

Приложение работает при запуске с компьютера(с android studio), но после генерации apk файла и дальнейшей загрузки в play market приложение перестает работать( если скачать приложение с play market и запустить). Я предполагаю, что проблема связана с google-services.json. Далее сама ошибка.

```
07-04 13:21:07.292 2872-12688/? E/Volley: [1511] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyC1Uz6ATRtZx_en5cR1o5VNnsVpyy0IDyE
07-04 13:21:07.292 2872-14532/? I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL : App validation failed
```

При попытке добавить ограничения(приложение для Android) в ключ(в google api console'е) выдает следующую ошибку :

```
07-04 13:13:15.610 2872-12685/? E/Volley: [1508] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyC1Uz6ATRtZx_en5cR1o5VNnsVpyy0IDyE
07-04 13:13:15.610 2872-12304/? I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: The Android package name and signing-certificate fingerprint, my.project.faq.findme and DAF5B744BA643591947DA26B2FBBEA8768D664E9, do not match the app restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.
```

Предполагаю, что добавляя ограничения в google consol'e, надо также добавить их в сам файл google-services.json, но я не нашел информации как это сделать.
Есть идеи, как это исправить?

Comment: Вы добавили key hash для релизного ключа в google api console?

Comment: @eugeneek  не совсем понимаю что это. Можете подробнее описать?